# Is $Tf = (f(-1), f(0), f(1)), T: \mathcal{C}[-1,1 ]$ surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

It's such a small thing, but I cant figure it out.

If I have $T: \mathcal{C}[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$, given by $Tf =  (f(-1), f(0), f(1))$, is that a surjective map? Proof or counterexample. Im cant seem to find a convincing argument that the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$ will be covered, I was trying to constuct some function that will take any value depending on coefficients, but no progress...

(Im trying to apply the isomorphism theorem for a problem, got stuck on this...)

Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, given three real numbers $x,y,z$, is there a continuous function $f$ on $[-1,1]$ such that $f(-1) = x$, $f(0) = y$, $f(1) = z$?

Hint: Try a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: hmmm. For any x,y,z, pick the polynomial with coefficients $a_0, a_1, a_2$, satisfying $x = a_0 - a_1 + a_2 $ etc etc..., something like this?